# How yo post to a database without a form php mysql html

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to post the fields `price` and `plateId` to a database table without using any form, when the user clicks the `Order` button. Would it be possible?  Otherwise, could you suggest an other solution?

```
<div class="menu">
  <img src="/images/wings.png" />
  <div>
    <span id="price">Price:$40.00</span>
    <div class="description">
      <span id="plateId">HOT WINGS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn">Order</button>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <img src="/images/chicken.png" />
  <div>
    <span id="price">Price:$70.00</span>
    <div class="description">
      <span>Cooked Chicken</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn">Order</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **AJAX** first and in your case you should collect information about `plateId` and `price` and return the data to **AJAX** so it can store in your database.

```
   $('#btn').click(function () {
     var orderInformation = {
       var price = $(#price).text();
       var plateId = $(#plateId).text();
     };

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'post-information-in-your-db.php',
       dataType: "json",
       data:(orderInformation),
       success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
       }
     }); 
   });
```

It is also possible to treat the data returned from the **variable** and different **display** shapes after `success`.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a server call through ajax by calling a javascript function as:

```
 function send_value() {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'get.php',
     dataType: "json",
     data:({"uniId":"test"}),
     success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     } 
  });
  return false;
  }
```

Pass data as an argument and put them as json in `data:({"uniId":"test"})`